# Why is "isActive" on a User returning false when I'm sure the User is in fact active?

Tags: apex, sharing

Long story short, I want to share a Contact record with a User given certain criteria in an Apex trigger. One of the things I want to check is if the User is active because creating a ContactShare object pointing to an inactive User would throw an error. So I do the following in my code:

```
    for (Contact c : Contacts)
    {
        system.debug('IsActive = ' + c.pse__Salesforce_User__r.isActive);
        //If this Contact's email also belongs to a User, AND that User is 
        //their Salesforce User Lookup, share this contact with the User.
        if(c.Email != null && userEmailMap.containsKey(c.Email) && (c.pse__Salesforce_User__c == userEmailMap.get(c.Email).ID) && (c.pse__Salesforce_User__r.isActive == TRUE)){

            ContactShare cs = new ContactShare(ContactID = c.ID, 
                                              UserorGroupId = userEmailMap.get(c.Email).ID, 
                                              ContactAccessLevel ='Read');

            contactsToManuallyShare.add(cs);
        }
    }
```

pse__Salesforce_User__r is a lookup to a User on the Contact.
I was testing this code on a User that I am 100% sure is Active, (the 'Active' Checkbox is checked) so you'll have to take my word on that part. But that debug message shows IsActive = false. I have this issue on any User I try this with. Why is that IsActive field not accurate? Am I using the wrong field?

Thanks

Comment: Where have you queried for the isActive field?  Triggers don't by default include values for parent records.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you've put Trigger.new into the Contacts variable. This is problematic, because relationship fields are not populated by default, and as it so happens, Boolean values default to a false value if you try to reference them without querying them. You can easily verify this behavior with this simple [Execute Anonymous](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_execute_anonymous.htm) Script:

```
Contact c = new Contact();
System.debug(c.Owner.IsActive); // = false
```

The solution is the [Aggregate-Query-Update](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html) pattern. Basically, you need to grab the records first:

```
// Aggregate Id values
Map<Id, User> users = new Map<Id, User>();
for(Contact c: Contacts) {
  users.put(c.pse__Salesforce_User__c, null);
}
// Query for parent records
users.putAll([SELECT Email, IsActive FROM User WHERE Id = :users.keySet()]);
// Do updates
ContactShare[] contactsToManuallyShare = new ContactShare[0];
for(Contact c: Contacts) {
  User u = users.get(c.pse__Salesforce_User__c);
  if(u != null && c.Email == u.Email && u.IsActive) {
    contactsToMauallyShare.add(
      new ContactShare(ContactId = c.Id, UserOrGroupId = u.Id, ContactAccessLevel = 'Read')
    );
  }
}
insert contactsToManuallyShare;
```

Comment: Thank you, after requerying within my method directly the value was correct. I was totally unaware that was an issue.

Answer (score -2):

can you give a try with this

```
if(c.Email != null && userEmailMap.containsKey(c.Email) && (c.pse__Salesforce_User__c == userEmailMap.get(c.Email).ID) && (c.pse__Salesforce_User__r.isActive))
```